# How would you use a sql server stored procedure that requires 2 parameters to produce a view in MVC 4

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, stored-procedures

I have the following stored procedure in sql server 2008 r2

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[cusGenDenialReport](@StartDate VARCHAR(11), @EndDate VARCHAR(11))
AS

BEGIN
SELECT     VisitTransactions.PatientVisitid AS PatientVisitid,   VisitTransactions.PaymentMethodId AS PaymentMethodId, 
                  VisitTransactions.Adjustments AS Adjustments, VisitTransactions.Transfers AS Transfers, Transactions.[Action] AS [action], Transactions.Type AS type, 
                  Transactions.Name AS name, Transactions.Amount AS Amount, VisitTransactions.Payments, PatientVisit.TicketNumber, TransactionDistributions.Code, 
                  InsuranceCarriers.Name AS InsName,  PatientVisitProcs.CPTCode AS CPT, PatientVisit.Visit AS DateOfVisit, VisitTransactions.LastModified AS DateOfEntry, Transactions.Note, 
                  PatientVisitProcsAgg.InsBalance AS InsBalance, PatientVisitProcsAgg.PatBalance AS PatBalance, Transactions.LastModified, 
                  Transactions.ActionTypeMId, MedLists.FunctionName, MedLists.Description AS PaymentType, 
                  DoctorFacility.ListName AS Doctor
FROM         VisitTransactions INNER JOIN
                  Transactions ON VisitTransactions.VisitTransactionsId = Transactions.VisitTransactionsId INNER JOIN
                  TransactionDistributions ON Transactions.TransactionsId = TransactionDistributions.TransactionsId INNER JOIN
                  PatientVisit ON VisitTransactions.PatientVisitid = PatientVisit.PatientVisitId INNER JOIN
                  InsuranceCarriers ON VisitTransactions.InsuranceCarriersId = InsuranceCarriers.InsuranceCarriersId INNER JOIN
                  PatientVisitAgg ON PatientVisit.PatientVisitId = PatientVisitAgg.PatientVisitId INNER JOIN
                  PatientVisitProcsAgg ON TransactionDistributions.PatientVisitProcsId = PatientVisitProcsAgg.PatientVisitProcsId INNER JOIN
                  MedLists ON Transactions.ActionTypeMId = MedLists.MedListsId INNER JOIN
                  PatientVisitProcs ON PatientVisitProcsAgg.PatientVisitProcsId = PatientVisitProcs.PatientVisitProcsId INNER JOIN
                  DoctorFacility ON PatientVisit.DoctorId = DoctorFacility.DoctorFacilityId
WHERE     (VisitTransactions.Payments = 0) AND VisitTransactions.LastModified BETWEEN @StartDate and @EndDate


END
```

I created a data model and named it demo10DenialReport.edmx from the result set of the preceeding stored procedure.

What I am needing to do is have the end-user input the start date and the end date into two different textboxes.  Then I want the view to display the filtered results.

My view looks like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<OEWebPortalMVCVer5.Models.cusGenDenialReport1_Result>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Denial";
}

<h2>Denial</h2>

<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")

@using (Html.BeginForm("startDate", "endDate", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <p> Start Date: @Html.TextBox("startDate") <br />
        End Date: @Html.TextBox("endDate") <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
    </p>
    }
</p>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PatientVisitid)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PaymentMethodId)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Adjustments)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Transfers)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.action)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.type)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.name)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Amount)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Payments)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TicketNumber)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Code)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.InsName)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CPT)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DateOfVisit)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DateOfEntry)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Note)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.InsBalance)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PatBalance)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastModified)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ActionTypeMId)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FunctionName)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PaymentType)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Doctor)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>



@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PatientVisitid)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PaymentMethodId)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Adjustments)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Transfers)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.action)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.type)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Amount)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Payments)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TicketNumber)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Code)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InsName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CPT)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateOfVisit)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateOfEntry)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Note)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InsBalance)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PatBalance)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastModified)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ActionTypeMId)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FunctionName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PaymentType)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Doctor)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
    </td>
</tr>
}

</table>
```

I am not worried about the Edit, details or delete link at the bottom (I know those are incorrect.

This is my partial controller:

```
        public ActionResult Denial(String startDate, String endDate)
    {

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(startDate))
        {
            return View();
        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(endDate))
        {
            return View();
        }

        return View();
    }
```

The error that it throws when I compile and run the code is this

```
NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
```

and it throws on this line

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
```

I think if I can get that error to stop I will be able to display the view.  Let me know if I am wrong

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want a null check to ignore the foreach erroring when the model is null.

```
@if( Model != null ) {
  foreach (var item in Model) {
   ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jafin - That took care of one error, now why doesn't my data display?

Comment: Upon further examination I found that the parameters are not being collected properly from the URL.  They are passed to the URL

Comment: Your form method is FormMethod.Get, which will post to the the URL, you need to set that to Post to get it posted in the body to your action.

Comment: Thank you again!  I knew it was something simple